# Flex Grid - ala titles - with md-card

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material, md-card

I trying to create a responsive list of cards that would have a minimum width, fill all available space (1, 2, 3 pieces in line according to browser size).

So far I have code what does that:

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <md-card style="min-width: 460px;" ng-repeat="teacher in tc.teachers" flex>
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-headline" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">{{ teacher.name }}</span>
        ... other elements ....
      </md-card-title-text>
      <md-card-title-media>
        <div class="md-media-lg card-media" style="height: 228px;">
          <img ng-if="teacher.image" ng-src="{{ tc.getImage( teacher ) }}" class="md-card-image" >
        </div>
      </md-card-title-media>
    </md-card-title>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

What does trick is in line #2 `style="min-width: 460px;"` and `flex`

However, problem what I facing is that last element is also 'flexed' to the whole width what looks ugly when for example there are 3 cards in a row and the last row has only 1 element...

**How I can adjust this last element to be 1/3 in this case and also be responsive to further size changes?**

I am using Angular 1.6.1 with angular-material.

Comment: What is css of `[flex]`? Could you please provide a code snipet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Make the card container  display:flex; & then give the cards(children of card flex container) this property flex-grow:1. Hope this helps with the limited amount of info you have provided.

Comment: No sure I understand the problem. As @bhv mentioned you should try to create a demo to show us. Based on my understanding I think you should not really use `raw css` to manage width of elements. Here is the beginning of something that may help you : https://jsfiddle.net/laguiz/7Loes916/ (you can play with responsive flex-... and layout-... : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use Angular Material **md-grid-list** and **md-grid-tile** (you can check the doc [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList) and [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridTile)), you can specify how many columns you want for each screen size (xs, sm, md, lg, etc.) the height of columns and a few other things.

And if there is a last row with, by example, only one element, this element will not be larger than the others.

You can use it like this :

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="3" md-cols-lg="4" md-row-height="100px">
    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="teacher in tc.teachers">
        <!-- width : 100% -> to make the cards gets the full width -->
        <md-card style="width:100%;">
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">{{ teacher.name }}</span>
                    ... other elements ....
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
        </md-card>
    </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FaIV8F1IQXdoaa1J6fxD?p=preview) is a working example.